# css styles are not applicable when textbox is disabled

Tags: css

When I set my `textbox.Enabled = false`, it loses all CSS Styles.
I can set it to `readonly`, and all CSS Styles works well.
But how can I keep css styles for `disabled` textbox?

Comment: (And a test-case, preferably on jsfiddle or similar.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much,

I found the solution to do it. There are no CSS style apply when I set `Enabled=false`.But when I set `disabled=true`,it works well.

Example:

```
[TextBox txtTest class="test" disabled="true"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can apply CSS styling on `disabled` inputs by using this:

```
input[disabled]
{
  /* Your CSS Styles */
  background-color:#F0F0F0 !important; 
  color:#303030 !important;
}
```

**or**

```
/* To make this work add class="disabled" in your HTML input tag (for IE6)*/
input[disabled='disabled'] 
{
  /* Your CSS Styles */
  background-color:#F0F0F0 !important; 
  color:#303030 !important;
}
```

and also You can apply CSS styling on `read-only` inputs by using this: (*optional*)

```
input[readonly]
{
  /* Your CSS Styles */
  background-color:#F0F0F0 !important; 
  color:#303030 !important;
}
```

Or else if you declared any `Id` or `class` to that input then replace `input` with that `Id` or `class` in the above code.

I am not sure about giving `!important`, once try without giving. If it works then **Ok**, otherwise consider `!important` in your CSS.

source: [link](http://dotnetdaily.net/tutorials/add-css-disabled-readonly-inputs/)

Comment: Thanks very much, it works for input[readonly], but doesn't work for inpt[disabled]

Comment: You should give `input[disabled]` not `inpt[disabled]` if you have given it right then go through this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:disabled)

Comment: @user1705172 Try the alternate way which i have updated in my answer.BTW which browser you are trying with?  and what is its version?

Comment: Thanks Mr_Green, I found the solution to do it. There are no CSS style apply when I set Enabled=false. But when I set disabled=true, it works well. Example: <TextBox txtTest class="test" disabled="true"></TextBox>

Answer (score 0):

There is a Slight difference between Read Only and Enabled. 
**Read Only** Can be Available only for the controls which will **get the users INPUT**. But **Enabled is available** to All the **Controls Commonly to Restrict the Usage Of it**.

**

```
- Enabled will affect the CSS not much But the Font Style(Color,Style), Control will not be available. 
- Read Only Does the Same Work Without Affecting Anything,Control Will be Available**
```